# Question about meaning of "compromising" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> After a colleague is kidnapped by the criminal multimillionaire she is spying on, Sam is ordered to kill him to keep him from being tortured and compromising the team. But her colleague delivers a stunning revelation - he has information on who tried to assassinate her in Tangier. If Sam carries out the order to kill him, she will never find out.

My instinct is that it has to do with informing the criminal multimillionaire by the person being tourtured and therfore put Sam and other colleague in danger.

Comment: Yes, your instinct is exactly right. To "compromise" a team of spies would be to reveal the team's existence and activities.

Answer (score 6):

"***Compromising the team"*** here implies that the person being tortured would ultimately give in to the torture and be forced to reveal sensitive information concerning the team. The revealed information would be harmful for the team's interests, in other words- *comprising the team*.

This definition of "*Compromise*" from [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compromise) would be helpful:

> <sup>2</sup>**Compromise**
>  <sup>*VERB*</sup>
>
> : to give up something that you want in order to reach an agreement : to settle differences by means of a compromise
>
> **: to expose (something) to risk or danger**
>
> : to damage or weaken (something)
>
> [. . .]
>
> <sup>*TRANSITIVE VERB*</sup>
>
> **3.b. to reveal or expose to an unauthorized person and especially to an enemy**
> *confidential information was compromised*
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster definition of “compromise”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compromise)</sub>